# how to interact between 2 python scripts?

Tags: python-3.x, variables, import

I'm writing program to run one script that takes pictures and writes the number into txt file and after its done it should tell other file you can read that txt file. I can't seem to import this "Perrasytas" variable to other script. It just says its not defined.

```
Script1
    if line==('echo:SD card ok'): 
                Perrasytas=0
                cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
                cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280)
                cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720)
                GPIO.output(4,GPIO.LOW)            
                with open(cnt, 'r') as f:
                    line = f.read()
                    num = int((line.split())[0])+1
                with open(cnt, 'w') as f:
                    f.write(str(num))
                    Perrasytas=1

Script2
    import Script1
    if Script1.Perrasytas == 1:
              cnt2='/home/pi/Prints_photos/counter.txt'
              with open(cnt2, 'r') as f:
                  num2 = f.read()
```

If I leave "Perrasytas=0" variable at the first line of code it does import, but it doesn't change its state..

is it even possible to do such communication thing between scripts?

Answer (score 0):

Importing a module only runs its code once -- the first time you import it. Since the value of `line` is probably not equal to `"echo:..."` when the import happens, the `if` block is never entered, and the `Perrasytas` variable is never set.

You could put all of that code into a function, and return the value of `Perrasytas` from that function. That way, you can execute that code whenever you call the function.

```
def get_perrasytas(line):
    if line==('echo:SD card ok'): 
        Perrasytas=0
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280)
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720)
        GPIO.output(4,GPIO.LOW)            
        with open(cnt, 'r') as f:
            line = f.read()
            num = int((line.split())[0])+1
        with open(cnt, 'w') as f:
            f.write(str(num))
            Perrasytas=1
    return Perrasytas
```

Then, you could call it like so:

```
import Script1
if Script1.get_perrasytas(line) == 1:
    cnt2='/home/pi/Prints_photos/counter.txt'
    with open(cnt2, 'r') as f:
        num2 = f.read()
```

Note that you will need to have `line` *before* you call the function, or include a way to get `line` *inside* the function.